# What is " int (**p)[2]; "?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, implicit-conversion

Here is the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = { {6, 2}, {3, 4} };
    
    int (**p)[2];
    p = a;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%p\n", (*p + i));
        printf("%d\n", *(*p + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I interpreted `int(**p)[2];` as a double pointer to a 1D array of size 2.

I drew this conclusion because:

1. `int *p[2];` means an array of integer pointers of size 2.
2. `int (*p)[2];` means an integer pointer pointing to a 1D array of size 2.

So,

3. `int **p[2];` means an array of integer double pointers of size 2.
4. `int (**p)[2];` means an integer double pointer pointing to a 1D array of size 2.

Out of 1, 2, 3 and 4 statements which are true and which are needed to be corrected?

Consequently, what would be the output of this code?

I tried [here](https://onlinegdb.com/_70gosROP).

Comment: You can use [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=+int+%28**p%29%5B2%5D%3B), to translate pretty much any expression to plain English.

Answer (score 5):

Your 'assertions' (1, 2, 3 and 4) are all essentially correct. However, I would use different, more *specific* terms and, especially, avoid the term, "double pointer". (That can be – and often is – mis-interpreted and/or misused.)

So:

1. `int *p[2];` declares `p` as an array of two pointers to integers;
2. `int (*p)[2];` declares `p` as a pointer to an array of two integers;
3. `int **p[2];` declares `p` as an array of two elements, each of which is a pointer to a pointer to an integer;
4. `int (**p)[2];` declares `p` as a pointer to a pointer to an array of two integers.

---

> *… what would be the output of this code?*

The code is ill-formed because of the `p = a;` line. Furthermore, the line, `printf("%d\n", *(*p + i));` exhibits undefined behaviour, because there is a mismatch between the format specifier (`%d`, which expects an `int` argument) and the provided argument (`*(*p + i)`, which has type `int*`).

---

A version of your code that does not exhibit undefined behaviour and may *possibly* do what you are looking for is the following (read the comments):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = { {6, 2}, {3, 4} };
    int(**p)[2];
    int(*t)[2] = &a[0]; // a pointer to an array of 2 integers (1st half of "a")
//  int(*t)[2] = a;     // Works the same as "a" decays to address of 1st element
    p = &t;             // "p" is now (correctly) a pointer to that pointer
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // Going beyond 2 elements is UB (but MAY work)
        printf("%p\n", (void*)(*p + i)); // Arguments for "%p" should be void*
        printf("%d\n",  (**p)[i]); // Dereference "p" twice then get array element
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int (*t)[2] = &a[0];` it is enough to: `int (*t)[2] = a;`

Comment: I am not criticizing the code, only showing how I would assign it.

Comment: @0___________ I got that, and also appreciate your comment (I even added it to the code, as an alternative). I was just "in need of coffee" when I used the full `&a[0]` expression without realizing that's **exactly** what `a` will translate to.

Comment: @AdrianMole This is just what I was looking for. This question was given to me as a practice problem and (int (**p)[2]; ) was interpreted as " an array of double pointers " or precisely, an array of pointer to pointers of size 2. ( Sorry for the term double pointer, but this is what I have been hearing recently)

Comment: I was like, " How the heck does this code work at all? " I thought of the program being wrong but needed a better understanding of what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

> Consequently, what would be the output of this code?

**Undefined**, as you access elements which do not belong to any object (outside the bounds).

> I interpreted int(**p)[2]; as a double pointer to a 1D array of size
> 2.

It is a pointer to pointer to 2 elements `int` array.

Double pointer is no very price term which is hard to interpret.

Comment: Short and to the point. I like it.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question in the title: _What is " int (**p)[2]; "?_

Comment: I got that now.

Answer (score 0):

The program is incorrect. The compiler should issue a message for this assignment

```
p=a;
```

that there are used incompatible pointer types.

The array a declared like

```
int a[2][2] = {{6, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

is implicitly converted to a pointer of the type `int ( * )[2]` in the expression statement shown above. So the right side operand has the type `int ( * )[2]` while the left side operand has the type `int ( ** )[2]`.

In this call of printf

```
printf("%p\n", (*p + i));
printf("%d\n", *(*p + i));
```

the expression `*p` has the type `int ( * )[2]` and the expression `*( *p + i )` has the type `int[2]`. So in any case these calls do not make a sense.

You could write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = { { 6, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    
    int ( *p )[2];
    p = a;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%p\n", ( void * )( p + i ) );
        for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d\n", *( *(p + i) + j ));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output migh look like

```
0x7ffc550ffc50
6
2
0x7ffc550ffc58
3
4
```

Or you could write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = { { 6, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
    
    int ( *p )[2];
    p = a;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%p\n", ( void * )( *p + i ) );
        printf( "%d\n", *( *p + i ) );
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
0x7ffc550ffc50
6
0x7ffc550ffc54
2
0x7ffc550ffc58
3
0x7ffc550ffc5c
4
```

Comment: I got your intuition. Thanks for guiding me.